# Pairing Xamarin with Mac running on WSL2

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I installed Mac with the [docker-osx](https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX) Big Sur image in docker inside WSL2 Ubuntu and now I'm trying to pair it with Mac from Visual Studio. I can connect to it with `localhost:50922` but after providing the username and password I'm getting the following error.

`An error occurred while trying to configure the SSH keys for authentication with '::1:50922'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the host name `localhost:50922`. I changed it to `127.0.0.1:50922` and it started working.